# How to trigger the scroll event of a slider reliably?

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex

We have a slider in our C# WinForms application. We update some other information on the UI when the [`Scroll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs. However, when setting the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property, we only notice the slider changes visually and the [`ValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs.

It works when using record/playback, but that depends on mouse coordinates.

How can I "scroll" reliably without depending on mouse coordinates?

Here's my form in its default size:

[image: Slider small]

and it works with this recording:

[image: Ranorex Recording]

but it stops working reliably as soon as the form is resized:

[image: Slider large]

I'm looking for a method to drag the slider from value 0 to value 3, independent of the size of the slider.

I can set the value of the slider in a code module like this:

```
void ITestModule.Run()
{
    Mouse.DefaultMoveTime = 300;
    Keyboard.DefaultKeyPressTime = 100;
    Delay.SpeedFactor = 1.0;

    SliderTestRepository.Instance.Form1.TrackBar1.Value = 3;
}
```

but this will only change the position of the slider and not fire the scroll events.

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: @TESTasy: sure. See my updated question. It's easily reproducible, since I'm still in evaluation and do not work on a real application yet.